# Merging Multiple (and different datasets)

Tags: r, dataframe, merge

I'd like to merge multiple (around ten) datasets in R. Quite a few of the datasets are different from each other, so I don't need to match them by row name or anything. I'd just like to paste them side by side, on a single dataframe so I can export them into a single sheet. For instance, I have the following two datasets:

| Month | Engagement | Test |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 51 | 1 |
| Feb | 123 | 2 |

| Variable | Engagement |
| --- | --- |
| Hot | 412 |
| Cold | 4124 |
| Warm | 4fd4 |

I'd simply like to put them side by side (as in left and right) in a single data frame for exporting purposes, like this:

| Month | Engagement | Test | Variable | Engagement |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 51 | 1 | Hot | 412 |
| Feb | 123 | 2 | Cold | 4124 |
| NA | NA | NA | Warm | 4fd4 |

Is there any way to accomplish this? It might seem like a strange request, but do let me know if I should provide any more info! Thank you so much.

Comment: If possible, please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the data in a list. Find the max number of rows from the list. For each dataframe subset the rows, dataframe with lower number of rows will be appended with `NA`'s.

```
data <- list(df1, df2)
n <- seq_len(max(sapply(data, nrow)))
result <- do.call(cbind, lapply(data, `[`, n, ))
result

#   Month Engagement Test Variable Engagement
#1    Jan         51    1      Hot        412
#2    Feb        123    2     Cold       4124
#NA  <NA>         NA   NA     Warm       4fd4
```

Answer (score 0):

Index both data then merge by the index and drop the index:

```r
df1 <- read.csv("Book1.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = "")
df2 <- read.csv("Book2.csv", header = TRUE, na.strings = "")

# Assign index to the dataframe
rownames(df1) <- 1:nrow(df1)
rownames(df2) <- 1:nrow(df2)

# Merge by index:
merged <- merge(df1, df2, by=0, all=TRUE) %>% 
  select(-1)
merged
```

Output:

```
  Month Engagement Test Variable Engagement
1   Jan         51    1      Hot        412
2   Feb        123    2     Cold       4124
3  <NA>         NA   NA     Warm       4fd4
```